# Compilation error while compiling 2.1.2 code on 3.0 iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

When I'm trying to compile 2.1.2 SDK code on 3.0 or higher version, it gives a compilation error saying "CFXMLTreeRef undeclared identifier". Below is the code snippet where it shows the error:

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>   //cause of the preoblem
#else
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#endif
```

I searched for the "CFXMLTreeRef" in 2.1.2 SDK and it's found, but in SDK version higher than 3.0, I couldn't find it.

Can anyone tell where can I find the declartion of "CFXMLTreeRef".

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks
Puru

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```